# MPI: MPI_recv with MPI_ANY_SOURCE can not receive messages from some processes

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I want to implement a system, where there are one receiver and multiple senders. Each sender keeps sending data to the receiver. The receiver waits to receive data and process it. Here is the toy example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int _mpi_numWorkers, _mpi_rank;

    // Initialize openMPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &_mpi_numWorkers);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &_mpi_rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    float *send_data = (float *)malloc(360 * 5000 * sizeof(float));
    MPI_Status receive_status;

    if (_mpi_rank == 0) {
        while (1) {
            MPI_Recv(send_data, 360 * 5000, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &receive_status);

            cout << "Receive from " << receive_status.MPI_SOURCE << endl;
        }
    } else {

        while (1){
            MPI_Send(send_data, 360 * 5000, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            //sleep(1);
        }
    }

    // Terminate
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that MPI_recv can only receive messages from up to two processes no matter how many processes I set it to run (when no sleep). I have tested this code on one single machine, and on multiple machines cases:

**Single Machine Case**

I run this code through the following command:

```
mpiexec -n 5 ./test_mpi
```

Then, the receiver only receive from senders with rank 1 and 2.

**Multiple Machine Case**

I run 4 senders and 1 receiver on 5 homogeneous physical machines. All of them connect to a 100Mbps switch. In this case, the receiver also only receives data from a subset of senders. I use the tcpdump to check the packet, and observe that some senders do not even send the message. (Those senders are blocked at MPI_send, but no tcp sequence increases and no re-transmission.)

For those two cases, if I make each sender sleep some time (decreasing the sending rate), the receiver can receive data from more senders.

Can somebody help me to understand why this happens?

**Environment**

Debian testing with openmpi-1.6

**Edit 2/4/16**

I include `<cstdlib>` in the code to prevent any compilation issues.

Comment: Well, including the `<cstdlib>` helps to define `malloc` and running it as `mpirun -np 5 test_mpi` seems to work fine for me. (Compiling as `mpic++ test_mpi.cpp -o test_mpi`)

Comment: Thanks for reply. You mean work because you can see 4 senders' data continuously??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI has no fairness guarantee in that respect, see e.g.

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/gropp/node92.html#Node92

That means what you see is perfectly "legal" from MPI's point of view. One page further in the link I gave, there's a snippet that supposedly helps with that issue. In short, you have to issue (asynchronous) receives for each possible sender manually, and then handle them in a manner that look "fair" to you.

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/gropp/node93.html#Node93

Comment: The tutorial guides me to the way I should do. However, the code in Node 93 has a bug. `MPI_Irecv( buf+j, 1, MPI_INT, j, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j] ); ` is not correct. It should be `MPI_Irecv( buf+j+1, 1, MPI_INT, j+1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j] ); `

Comment: @Sunghlin, at best `j+1` should be replaced with `statuses[i].MPI_SOURCE` to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Sunghlin Probably the tutorial example is a port of the fortan-version (next page), and fortran usually starts indices at 1 instead of 0. Good catch anyway :-) PS I didn't try out any of this, just googled.

Comment: @hristolliev, You are right. At that time, I just want to make the modification as small as possible.